# How to launch a new ec2 instance via snapshot and cli

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli, ec2-ami

I have an EC2 instance snapshot, and I'd like to launch a new VM using it.

Can I use the AWS CLI (EC2 CLI) tools to launch a new instance?  If so, can anyone share  links/tutorials that describe the process?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an AMI from the snapshot of your root volume, for you to be able to launch an instance. This can be accomplished using the `aws cli` commands: `register-image` and `run-instances`. You can get an idea from [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-launch-snapshot.html)